# Is the word "arroba" (@ on keyboard) from Arabic?

Tags: etimología, vocabulario-técnico, símbolos, árabe, keyboard

The Wikipedia page for Spanish words derived from Arabic includes “arroba”, without a definition.

In Latin America it is widely used for the @symbol on computer keyboards. 
If *arroba* is derived from Arabic, what is its original meaning?

Answer (score 3):

According to the DLE, the word *[arroba](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3ljwHF8)* comes from Arabic *arrúb‘*, and this one from [Classical Arabic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Arabic) *rub‘*, meaning "a fourth part". In Spanish it was just a weight measure, equivalent to 11.502 kg.

It could be interesting to know... a fourth part of what? According to the Spanish Wikipedia, an *[arroba](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arroba_(unidad_de_masa))* was the fourth part of a *[quintal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintal)*, a weight measure equivalent to 100 *libras castellanas*.

Comment: Which answers the OP original question while leaving open the intriguing question of why the @ symbol is named after the fourth part of a _quintal_.

Comment: @mdewey that could be another great question for this site. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Otros apuntes sobre la @.

El académico italiano Giorgio Stabile descubrió una carta enviada desde Sevilla a Roma en 1536, donde se discutía la llegada a España de tres barcos que navegaban desde el Nuevo Mundo. Indicaba que se había vendido un ánfora de vino y "ánfora" había sido reemplazada con el símbolo @ como una abreviatura.

Según la [Wikilengua](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Arroba): "En los países anglosajones se le ha llamado 'at sign' y 'commercial at', pues antecedía el precio por unidad (3 books @ £20 = £60). De ahí que ocasionalmente reciba en español el nombre de 'a comercial'.".

Y según Keith Houston, autor de "Caracteres oscuros: La vida secreta de puntuación": "el símbolo @ apareció en las máquinas de escribir antes del final del siglo XIX ... formó parte de los teclados, porque era una herramienta de trabajo y tenía un uso comercial".
Y, como las máquinas de escribir lo incluían, pasó a los primeros teclados de los computadores.

El símbolo @ fue seleccionado por Ray Tomlinson, el padre del e-mail, entre los menos usados del teclado como separador entre el nombre del usuario, al que va dirigido el correo, y la máquina, donde está la cuenta de correo. Una decisión de segundos que convirtió al símbolo @ en la imagen de Internet.